# Cannot download file using DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am currently trying to download using DownloadManager class in my Android app. Below is my Code :

**DownloadHelper.Class**

```
public class DownloadHelper {
    DownloadManager downloadManager;
    Context context;
    public DownloadHelper(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    public long downloadData (Uri uri,String fileName,String mimeType) {

        long downloadReference;

        downloadManager = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.downloading_file));
        request.setDescription(fileName);
        request.setMimeType(mimeType);
        request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true);
        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context,Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,fileName);
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE);
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
                | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
        downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);


        return downloadReference;
    }
}
```

and I called it in my custom adapter class like below :

```
private void downloadFile(String url,String fileName,String mimeType) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadHelper  downloadHelper = new DownloadHelper(mContext);
        downloadHelper.downloadData(uri,fileName,mimeType);
}
```

The problem is whenever I call the `downloadFile` method, it shows download icon on my status bar for less than 1 sec, then it disappears. I check my download folder and it says downloading file. What concerned me is the file is relatively small (1.5kb) and it has been showing downloading file forever. Any solution perhaps for this problem? Thanks

Here is my DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor() result :

```
0{
status=194
_id=5270
09-19 15:12:11.198 13580-13580/com.example.project I/System.out:    local_filename=null
09-19 15:12:11.198 13580-13580/com.example.project I/System.out:    mediaprovider_uri=null
09-19 15:12:11.198 13580-13580/com.example.project I/System.out:    destination=4
09-19 15:12:11.198 13580-13580/com.example.project I/System.out:    title=Downloading file
09-19 15:12:11.198 13580-13580/com.example.project I/System.out:    description=ic_bullet.png
09-19 15:12:11.199 13580-13580/com.example.project I/System.out:    hint=file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.project/files/Download/ic_bullet.png
09-19 15:12:11.199 13580-13580/com.example.project I/System.out:    media_type=image/png
09-19 15:12:11.199 13580-13580/com.example.project I/System.out:    total_size=-1
09-19 15:12:11.199 13580-13580/com.example.project I/System.out:    last_modified_timestamp=1505808726864
09-19 15:12:11.199 13580-13580/com.example.project I/System.out:    bytes_so_far=0
09-19 15:12:11.199 13580-13580/com.example.project I/System.out:    allow_write=0
09-19 15:12:11.199 13580-13580/com.example.project I/System.out:    local_uri=null
09-19 15:12:11.199 13580-13580/com.example.project I/System.out:    reason=placeholder
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you try to download and from where. What is original size?

Comment: @greenapps I tried to download from my server a png picture which is 1.5kb in size

Comment: what does `DownloadManager#query()` return?

Comment: @pskink : the status says : STATUS_PAUSED and reason : PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY

Comment: hmm, `PAUSED_WAITING_TO_RETRY`: *"Value of COLUMN_REASON when the download is paused because some network error occurred and the download manager is waiting before retrying the request."*

Comment: @pskink : I'm working on stable network, downloading outside my apps is working and I've also set permission to use internet and write storage

Comment: ok so post the output of `DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor()` - maybe it will be more helpful

Comment: @pskink I've updated my question above. Please check it. Thanks

Comment: to me, nothing suspicious ;-(, i have no idea to be honest...

Comment: @pskink after doing some checking I've found out that the apps are able to download from https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Beauty.jpg , but I can't download from my server, my server have a signed SSL (both of the sites are https) and also the log doesn't throw any security error. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered to run downloadFile on the separate thread (not on the UI thread)?

Comment: did that before, but still It produced the same result

Answer (score 0):

did you you add internet permission in `Manifest`

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: my manifest permission : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />